# Replace NaN with values in a row from previous matching values in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following data frame (df).

```
df
     city    zip_code
0    city1  90287
1    city2  90288
2    city3  80023
3    city4  90210
4    city1  NaN
5    city4  NaN
6    city7  NaN
7    NaN    90210
8    NaN    80023
```

And I want to get to this state:

```
    city     zip_code
0   city1   90287
1   city2   90288
2   city3   80023
3   city4   90210
4   city1   90287
5   city4   90210
6   city7   NaN
7   city4   90210
8   city3   80023
```

I want to go through both columns and replace NaN with appropriate zip_code or city.

Here is what I have done but as you can see it didn't fully work.

```
bool_series = pd.notnull(df['city'])
df_1=df[bool_series].dropna()
dict_df_1=df_1.to_dict(orient='records')

d={}
for i in range(len(dict_df_1)):
    d[dict_df_1[i]['city']]=dict_df_1[i]['zip_code']
d1={}
for i in range(len(dict_df_1)):
    d1[dict_df_1[i]['zip_code']]=dict_df_1[i]['city']
d.update(d1)

df['zip_mapped']=df['city'].map(d)
df['city_mapped']=df['zip_code'].map(d)

df

     city   zip_code    zip_mapped  city_mapped
0    city1     90287    90287         city1
1   city2      90288    90288         city2
2   city3      80023    80023         city3
3   city4      90210    90210         city4
4   city1       NaN     90287         NaN
5   city4       NaN     90210         NaN
6   city7       NaN      NaN          NaN
7   NaN        90210    NaN           city4
8   NaN        80023    NaN           city3
​
```

If columns 'zip_mapped' and 'city_mapped' were properly populated I would have just replaced them with original cols. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Check groupby.ffill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try `fillna` twice on different groupby:

```
df.zip_code = df.zip_code.fillna(df.zip_code.groupby(df.city).transform('first'))

df.city = df.city.fillna(df.city.groupby(df.zip_code).transform('first'))
```

Output:

```
    city  zip_code
0  city1   90287.0
1  city2   90288.0
2  city3   80023.0
3  city4   90210.0
4  city1   90287.0
5  city4   90210.0
6  city7       NaN
7  city4   90210.0
8  city3   80023.0
```